# Cypress sends cookies automatically on cy.request

Tags: cypress

I have a scenario where I want to send a POST request using `cy.request()` after the application has started. And I see that cookies are sent together which is according to the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Cookies-are-automatically-sent-and-received).

The request I send should not use the cookies and use an bearer token for authentication.
Is it possible to say explicitly to cypress not to use the cookies when sending the request ?

Comment: I am using an workaround now to delete the cookie and set the cookie again after the request is sent.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the way to go, unless you are able to cut out the step that retrieves those cookies in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I just added a comment here https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/959.

What I did was create a command that clears the cookies, runs a callback, and then restores them back:

```js
/**
 * Clears cookies before executing a callback and then restores the cookies.
 * @param {Function} callback
 * @param {{ domain, log, timeout }} options https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/getcookies#Arguments
 */
Cypress.Commands.add('ignoreCookiesOnce', (callback, options) => {
  return cy.getCookies(options).then(cookies => {
    // Clear cookies
    cy.clearCookies(options)

    // Execute callback
    callback()

    // Restore cookies
    cookies.forEach(({name, value, ...rest}) => {
      cy.setCookie(name, value, rest)
    })
  })
})
```

Then you could do:

```js
cy.ignoreCookiesOnce(
  () => {
    cy.request({
      url: 'https://...',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Cookie: 'whateveryouwant'
      },
      body: `...`
    }).then(({body}) => body)
  },
  {domain: 'yourdomain.com'} // optional
)
```

---

Note, in some cases, you might want to pass specific cookies to ignore or pick. You can do that by enhancing the command like this:

```js
/**
 * Clears cookies before executing a callback and then restores the cookies.
 * Usage:
 *  1. cy.ignoreCookiesOnce(() => cy.visit(...))
 *  2. cy.ignoreCookiesOnce(() => cy.request(...), { domain: 'yourdomain.com'})
 *  3. cy.ignoreCookiesOnce(() => cy.visit(...), { cookies: ['foo', 'bar']})
 *  4. cy.ignoreCookiesOnce(() => cy.request(...), { except: ['foo', 'bar']})
 * @param {Function} callback
 * @param {{ cookies: Array, except: Array, domain: string, log, timeout }} options https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/getcookies#Arguments
 */
Cypress.Commands.add('ignoreCookiesOnce', (callback, options = {}) => {
  Cypress.Cookies.debug(true, {verbose: true})
  let {cookies, except, ...cyOptions} = options

  return cy.getCookies(cyOptions).then((all = []) => {
    // Obtain cookies from options
    if (Array.isArray(cookies) && cookies.length > 0) {
      cookies = cookies.map(n => all.find(c => c.name === n))
    } else if (Array.isArray(except) && except.length > 0) {
      cookies = all.filter(c => !except.includes(c.name))
    } else {
      cookies = all
    }

    // Clear cookies
    if (cookies === all) {
      cy.clearCookies(cyOptions) // clear all
    } else {
      cookies.forEach(c => cy.clearCookie(c.name, cyOptions))
    }

    // Execute callback
    callback()

    // Restore cookies
    cookies.forEach(({name, value, ...rest}) => {
      cy.setCookie(name, value, rest)
    })
  })
})
```